# How to add decoration to link in CSS?

Tags: css

I have the following which works:

```
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a{
color:#333333 !important;
}
```

And I want to be able to add the following to it:

```
a:link {text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
a:active {text-decoration:none;}
```

However, when I do this:

```
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a{
color:#333333 !important;
a:link {text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
a:active {text-decoration:none;}
}
```

... in Google Chrome's Inspect Element it shows an error "Unknown property name" for the added CSS, and it doesn't have any effect. What I'm trying to do, is do what the designed wants which is to have these Nav links have no decoration and underline the link on hover only.

What am I doing wrong? How should these text-decorations be added?

I have already tried this based on the answers I got here, is this correct?

```
/* bottom section Nav links in footer */
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a{ color:#333333 !important; text-decoration:none;}
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a:link {text-decoration:none;}
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a:active {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: Why would you think nesting style declarations would work in CSS? You need to move the `a:*` lines outside the `a` selector

Comment: Why are you putting your CSS for `:link`, `:visited` etc inside the CSS for `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the styles to `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover` and `:active` inside the css styling block for the `a` element. That will not work. Instead try the following

`#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a{
color:#333333 !important; text-decoration:none;
}`

`#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}`

Comment: Put all the common styles in the rules for `a`, use the individual states `:hover`, etc, to style specifically for those states.

Comment: Of course, that would be the way to go about it. I just wrote it like that just to make sure Edward didnt get confused. Edited now.

Comment: Can you give a complete example of what you are referring too?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'complete example', but those 2 lines are the complete thing according to your question. All the styles you had mentioned in the question can be applied by just these 2 lines here, so the `a` tag will have `color:#333333`, the `:link`, `:visited` and `:active` will have `text-decoration:none` and the `:hover` will have a `text-decoration:underline`

Comment: @Nibhrit But what groups these all together so this online applies to #s5_bottom_menu_wrap? It looks to me like a:hover {text-decoration:underline;} would apply to all the CSS including those outside of #s5_bottom_menu_wrap?

Comment: @Edward, good point, that's my bad. The rule should be `#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}`. 
Edited my response.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest the selectors in CSS, you need to do it like this

```
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a:link,
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a:visited,
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a:hover,
#s5_bottom_menu_wrap a:active {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

If you want nesting convenience, than take a look at CSS Preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: In your example, how would the text-decoration be added to be none or underline for each one?

Comment: @Edward If you want all the links on your page to have no underline than you should remove ids from my selector

Comment: No on the whole page, just this section of the footer that deals with "#s5_bottom_menu_wrap".

Comment: @Edward you can either keep none, or underline, and how to target them? the selectors are already provided in my answer